# What can be a subexpression?

Tags: c++, expression, sequence-points

I read "C++.Primer plus. Stephen Prata"(6th edition). 
On page 209 was:

> ```
> y = (4 + x++) + (6 + x++);
> ```
>
> The expression `4 + x++` is not a full
>   expression, so C++ does not guarantee that `x` will be incremented
>   immediately after the subexpression `4 + x++` is evaluated. Here the
>   full expression is the entire assignment statement, and the semicolon
>   marks the sequence point, so all that C++ guarantees is that `x` will
>   have been incremented twice by the time the program moves to the
>   following statement. C++ does not specify whether `x` is incremented
>   after each subexpression is evaluated or only after all the
>   expressions have been evaluated, which is why you should avoid
>   statements of this kind.

And I read "Sequence Points and Expression Evaluation" Visual Systems Journal, August 2002. Klaus Kreft & Angelika Langer.
There was:

> ```
>  x[i]=i++ + 1;
> ```
>
> Let's assume variable `i` has the value `1` before we enter the statement.
>   What will be the result of evaluation of this expression? The correct
>   answer is: we don't know.  However, programmers ever too often believe
>   that they know what this program fragment does. Typical answers
>   include: "`x[1]` will have the value `2`", or "`x[2]` will have the value
>   `2`", or even "`x[1]` will have the value `3`".
>
> The third option is definitely wrong. This will not happen because `i++`
>   is a postfix increment and returns `i`'s initial value `1`; hence the
>   value of the right hand side of the assignment is `2`, and definitely
>   not `3`. [...]  So far so good, but we do not know
>   which entry of the array `x` will be modified.  Will the index be `1` or `2`
>   when the right hand side value will be assigned to `x[i]`?
>
> There is no definite answer to this question. It fully depends on the
>   order in which the compiler evaluates the subexpressions.  If the
>   compiler starts on the right hand side of the assignment and evaluates
>   `i++ + 1` before it figures out which position in the array `x` must be
>   assigned to then `x[2]` will be modified because `i` will have already
>   been incremented in the course of evaluating the subexpression `i++`. 
>   Conversely, if the compiler starts on the left hand side and figures
>   out that it must assign to position `i` in array `x`, which at that time
>   will still be position `1`, before it evaluates the right hand side then
>   we'll end up with a modification of `x[1]`.  Both outcomes are equally
>   likely and equally correct. "

How understand where is subexpression? 
`4 + x++` and `6 + x++` are subexpressions, because they are into round brackets?
`x[i]` and `i++ + 1` are subexpression? Why?
I'm interested in this, because I want to understand where side effect can happened in the hypothesis.

Comment: The entire premise of this question seems questionable. E.g. 1.9/15 clearly says that "The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator". Patently, to evaluate `a + b` you first need to evaluate `a` and `b`. What isn't sequences are `a` and `b` with respect to each other. Or, in your code, what's problematic are the two separate expressions `x++` with respect to each other. Since neither is sequenced before the other, the program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @KerrekSB C++11 <-> sequence points.

Comment: @dyp: I'm not sure if this question is about a historic, obsolete standard; in any case, I don't think `4 + x++` was ever ambiguous. The `x++` is evaluated before the `+`. The problem comes from the *other* `x++`. The reasons may have changed, but I believe this was always undefined behaviour. It was never guaranteed that `x` would be incremented twice.

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree, it is also UB with the Sequence Point model. I just think it won't help much arguing about a 12 year old paper and seemingly similarly old book by using a Standard with a new/revised model of evaluation.

Comment: @dyp Said book is apparently only five years old and claims to cover C++11. Oh well.

Comment: @T.C. It ain't called the Primer *plus* for no reason ;) -- But seriously, what's the relation to the C++ Primer?

Comment: @dyp Apparently no relation.

Comment: The only thing you can know about these pieces of code is that a program that executes them is not a valid C++ program. I wouldn't trust any of these sources regarding anything.

Comment: Clearly they mean "an expression which is part of another expression"

Comment: Not part of the question, but "There is no definite answer to this question." is false. There is a definite answer: the expression causes undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can be a subexpression?

**Any** *expression* can be a subexpression. Although, some expressions may not be subexpressions of certain other expressions.

> `4 + x++` and `6 + x++` are subexpressions

Correct. Both of those are arithmetic expressions, additions to be more specific.

> because they are into round brackets?

Well, sort of. Being inside parentheses, they are indeed the subexpression of the parenthesized expression.

<sup>†</sup> In general, they're subexpressions because they're expressions, but are also part of another expression.

> `x[i]` and `i++ + 1` are subexpression? Why?

Yes, they are. See <sup>†</sup>.

Here is a handy list of all possible [expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions) in c++.

Let's find the subexpressions in `y = (4 + x++) + (6 + x++);`. The first expression that has no subexpressions is `4`. It is a literal. It is a subexpression of `4 + x++` which is an addition. Additions have the form `A + B`. In this case, subexpression A is `4` an subexpressiond B is `x++`, which is a post increment. Oh, but that contains a subexpression too: `x`. It is an identifier, and contains no subexpressions. `4 + x++` is a subexpression of the parenthesized expression `(4 + x++)`. That is a subexpression of `(4 + x++) + (6 + x++)` which is a subexpression of `y = (4 + x++) + (6 + x++);` which is an assignment. The assignement is a full-expression - not a subexpression. I left some of the subexpressions unexplored, and I shall leave them as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: user2079303, thank you very much for the detailed answer and that link. I didn't find information about "subexpression", probably, that I was looking it at Russian sites. ;) I'm very glad, that here people ready to help.

Comment: It turns out, that "x++" named a decrement-expression or I'm wrong?

Comment: @Anastasia_P no, it's an *increment* expression. More specifically, a post increment.

Comment: Do you have any links about side effect?

Answer (score 2):

Breaking this down, the line

```
y = (4 + x++) + (6 + x++);
```

is an expression-statement. Such a thing consists of an expression followed by a `;`, so

```
y = (4 + x++) + (6 + x++)
```

is an expression.

Since this expression *is **not*** part of another expression (but only of an expression-*statement*), it is a *full-expression*. A *sub-expression* on the other hand is an expression that *is* part of another expression. In the following, I will use capital letters to name expressions, rather than C++ identifiers.

The full-expression above is an assignment-expression of the form:

```
y = A
```

where A is the remaining additive-expression

```
(4 + x++) + (6 + x++)
```

An additive expression is of the form `X + Y`, so we break this down into *two* expressions

```
(4 + x++)
(6 + x++)
```

The first one consists of an expression of the form `(Z)`, where `Z` is `4 + x++`. And `4 + x++` consists of two expressions `4` and `x++`. And so on. All of these expressions are part of

```
y = (4 + x++) + (6 + x++)
```

and hence they are *sub-expressions* of the above expression.